# Why is there a limit on the length of a regex pattern in Text.Regex.Posix?

Tags: haskell

I'm seeing an odd arbitrary limit on the length of a regular expression pattern where, after a string of 30 characters, funny things start to happen.

Simple GHCI example:

```
> import Text.Regex.Posix
> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789" =~ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123" :: String
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123"
> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789" =~ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234" :: String
""
```

The only difference is the addition of the `4` at the end of the last pattern. It's a valid regex and *should* match but it gives me an empty string.

It gets even weirder if I add a few more valid characters to the pattern:

```
> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789" =~ "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567" :: String
"ab"
```

It tells me it only matches `ab` when clearly that's wrong.

My environment:

- Stack version 1.1.2 (resolver lts-6.7)
- GHC version 7.10.3
- OS: Windows 10
- regex-posix-0.95.2

A complete uninstall and reinstall of Stack and all packages did not solve the problem

Comment: Which version of the regex-posix library are you using? I can't reproduce

Comment: I'm assuming it's `regex-posix-0.95.2` since that's what's [listed on stackage for resolver `lts-5.0`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-5.0)

Comment: Same here. I'm not on windows though, but FWIW I can't reproduce on Linux.

Comment: I just upgraded to `lts-6.7` which uses the same `regex-posix-0.95.2` package and I'm getting the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following [this discussion](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues/144#issuecomment-52845706), it seems like there are other issues with this library stemming from the underlying C code not being properly ported to 64-bit architecture.

I have switched to the [regex-tdfa](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa) package and no longer have these problems.